# Haskell solution for InterviewStreet String Similarity challenge

Tags: string, algorithm, haskell

This is my best attempt to solve the [String Similarity](https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4edb8abd7cacd) challenge for InterviewStreet.

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO


sumSimilarities s = (T.length s) + (sum $ Prelude.map (similarity s) (Prelude.tail $ tails s))

similarity :: Text -> Text -> Int
similarity a b = case commonPrefixes a b of
                     Just (x,_,_) -> T.length x
                     Nothing -> 0

main = do
    cases <- fmap read getLine
    inputs <- replicateM cases TIO.getLine
    forM_ inputs $ print . sumSimilarities
```

It only passes 7/10 of the test cases. Test cases 7, 8, and 9 fail because they exceed the allotted execution time.

I'm half trying to verify that this is indeed possible to solve in Haskell and half looking for what an optimized Haskell program looks like.

Thanks!
   Tyler

Comment: What's `commonPrefixes`?

Comment: It's actually built into the Data.Text library.

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/latest/doc/html/Data-Text.html#v:commonPrefixes

Comment: It's possible that doing it with `ByteString`s is faster. But you'll probably need a better algorithm. Yours is quadratic in the worst case, there are probably some bad cases included on purpose.

Comment: It would interesting to know if the equivalent C/Java program completes in the time limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like [user5402](https://stackoverflow.com/users/866915/user5402), I'd be curious whether an equivalent (for certain values of equivalent) C programme would finish within the time limit or also time out. If it would, it would be interesting to see whether an equivalent programme using `ByteString`s could finish in time. - Not that `ByteString`s are per se faster than `Text`, but since the input must be converted to the internal representation of `Text` while `ByteString` takes it as is, that might make a difference. Another possible reason that `ByteString`s might be faster - if the testing machines have 32-bit GHCs - would be that [text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text)'s fusion at least used to need more registers than generally available on 32 bit architectures to get full profit [a long time ago, in the days of text-0.5 to text-0.7, on my 32-bit box, [bytestring](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring) used to be quite a bit faster, no idea whether that still holds for newer [text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) versions].

Okay, since [user5402](https://stackoverflow.com/users/866915/user5402) has verified that the naïve algorithm is fast enough in C, I've gone ahead and wrote an implementation of the naïve algorithm using `ByteString`s

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Main (main) where

import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
import qualified Data.ByteString.Unsafe as U
import Control.Monad
import Data.Word

main :: IO ()
main = do
    cl <- C.getLine
    case C.readInt cl of
      Just (cases,_) -> replicateM_ cases (C.getLine >>= print . similarity)
      Nothing -> return ()

-- Just to keep the condition readable.
(?) :: B.ByteString -> Int -> Word8
(?) = U.unsafeIndex

similarity :: B.ByteString -> Int
similarity bs
    | len == 0  = 0
    | otherwise = go len 1
      where
        !len = B.length bs
        go !acc i
            | i < len   = go (acc + prf 0 i) (i+1)
            | otherwise = acc
        prf !k j
            | j < len && bs ? k == bs ? j   = prf (k+1) (j+1)
            | otherwise = k
```

and compared it to the OP's `Text` version on some bad cases. On my box, that is more than four times faster than the `Text` version, so it'd be interesting whether that's fast enough (the C version is another 4.5 times faster, so it may well not be).

However, I consider it more likely that the time limit is exceeded due to using the naïve algorithm that has quadratic worst-case behaviour. Probably there are test cases that evoke the worst-case for the naïve algorithm.

So the solution would be to use an algorithm that scales better, optimally linear. One linear algorithm to compute the similarity of a string is the [Z-algorithm](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3107).

The idea is simple (but, like most good ideas, not easy to have). Let us call a (non-empty) substring that is also a prefix of the string a prefix-substring. To avoid recomputation, the algorithm uses a window of the prefix-substring starting before the currently considered index that extends farthest to the right (initially, the window is empty).

Variables used and invariants of the algorithm:

- `i`, the index under consideration, starts at 1 (for 0-based indexing; the entire string is not considered) and is incremented to `length - 1`
- `left` and `right`, the first and last index of the prefix-substring window; invariants:

  1. `left < i`, `left <= right < length(S)`, either `left > 0` or `right < 1`,
  2. if `left > 0`, then `S[left .. right]` is the maximal common prefix of `S` and `S[left .. ]`,
  3. if `1 <= j < i` and `S[j .. k]` is a prefix of `S`, then `k <= right`
- An array `Z`, invariant: for `1 <= k < i`, `Z[k]` contains the length of the longest common prefix of `S[k .. ]` and `S`.

The algorithm:

1. Set `i = 1`, `left = right = 0` (any values with `left <= right < 1` are allowed), and set `Z[j] = 0` for all indices `1 <= j < length(S)`.
2. If `i == length(S)`, stop.
3. If `i > right`, find the length `l` of the longest common prefix of `S` and `S[i .. ]`, store it in `Z[i]`. If `l > 0` we have found a window extending farther right than the previous, then set `left = i` and `right = i+l-1`, otherwise leave them unchanged. Increment `i` and go to 2.
4. Here `left < i <= right`, so the substring `S[i .. right]` is known - since `S[left .. right]` is a prefix of `S`, it is equal to `S[i-left .. right-left]`.

   Now consider the longest common prefix of `S` with the substring starting at index `i - left`.
   Its length is `Z[i-left]`, hence `S[k] = S[i-left + k]` for `0 <= k < Z[i-left]` and
   `S[Z[i-left]] ≠ S[i-left+Z[i-left]]`. Now, if `Z[i-left] <= right-i`, then `i + Z[i-left]` is inside the known window, therefore

   ```
   S[i + Z[i-left]] = S[i-left + Z[i-left]] ≠ S[Z[i-left]]
   S[i + k]         = S[i-left + k]         = S[k]   for 0 <= k < Z[i-left]
   ```

   and we see that the length of the longest common prefix of `S` and `S[i .. ]` has length `Z[i-left]`.
   Then set `Z[i] = Z[i-left]`, increment `i`, and go to 2.

   Otherwise, `S[i .. right]` is a prefix of `S` and we check how far it extends, starting the comparison of characters at the indices `right+1` and `right+1 - i`. Let the length be `l`. Set `Z[i] = l`, `left = i`, `right = i + l - 1`, increment `i`, and go to 2.

Since the window never moves left, and the comparisons always start after the end of the window, each character in the string is compared at most once successfully to an earlier character in the string, and for each starting index, there is at most one unsuccessful comparison, therefore the algorithm is linear.

The code (using `ByteString` out of habit, ought to be trivially portable to `Text`):

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Main (main) where

import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
import qualified Data.ByteString.Unsafe as U
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array.Base
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad
import Data.Word

main :: IO ()
main = do
    cl <- C.getLine
    case C.readInt cl of
      Just (cases,_) -> replicateM_ cases (C.getLine >>= print . similarity)
      Nothing -> return ()

-- Just to keep the condition readable.
(?) :: B.ByteString -> Int -> Word8
(?) = U.unsafeIndex

-- Calculate the similarity of a string using the Z-algorithm
similarity :: B.ByteString -> Int
similarity bs
    | len == 0  = 0
    | otherwise = runST getSim
      where
        !len = B.length bs
        getSim = do
            za <- newArray (0,len-1) 0 :: ST s (STUArray s Int Int)
            -- The common prefix of the string with itself is entire string.
            unsafeWrite za 0 len
            let -- Find the length of the common prefix.
                go !k j
                    | j < len && (bs ? j == bs ? k) = go (k+1) (j+1)
                    | otherwise = return k
                -- The window with indices in [left .. right] is the prefix-substring
                -- starting before i that extends farthest.
                loop !left !right i
                    | i >= len  = count 0 0 -- when done, sum
                    | i > right = do
                        -- We're outside the window, simply
                        -- find the length of the common prefix
                        -- and store it in the Z-array.
                        w <- go 0 i
                        unsafeWrite za i w
                        if w > 0
                          -- We got a non-empty common prefix and a new window.
                          then loop i (i+w-1) (i+1)
                          -- No new window, same procedure at next index.
                          else loop left right (i+1)
                    | otherwise = do
                        -- We're inside the window, so the substring starting at
                        -- (i - left) has a common prefix with the substring
                        -- starting at i of length at least (right - i + 1)
                        -- (since the [left .. right] window is a prefix of bs).
                        -- But we already know how long the common prefix
                        -- starting at (i - left) is.
                        z <- unsafeRead za (i-left)
                        let !s = right-i+1 -- length of known prefix starting at i
                        if z < s
                          -- If the common prefix of the substring starting at
                          -- (i - left) is shorter than the rest of the window,
                          -- the common prefix of the substring starting at i
                          -- is the same. Store it and move on with the same window.
                          then do
                              unsafeWrite za i z
                              loop left right (i+1)
                          else do
                              -- Otherwise, find out how far the common prefix
                              -- extends, starting at (right + 1) == s + i.
                              w <- go s (s+i)
                              unsafeWrite za i w
                              loop i (i+w-1) (i+1)
                count !acc i
                    | i == len  = return acc
                    | otherwise = do
                        n <- unsafeRead za i
                        count (acc+n) (i+1)
            loop 0 0 1
```

Comment: Just a question, when is it appropiate to use "unsafe" in haskell, I notice this is a ST array inside the ST monad, is does that affect 'safety' in anyway?

Comment: It is appropriate to use `unsafeWhatever` if you can prove that it is safe and it yields an advantage over the alternative. Here, `unsafe` just means "Thanks, I checked the validity of the index myself, no need to repeat it". Using the `ST` monad is perfectly safe, the compiler guarantees that nothing can access the array from outside the computation by creating a unique state type parameter.

Comment: I have verified that a tight loop in C completes in the time limit, e.g. `  for (i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    char *s = buf+i;
    char *t = buf;
    while (*s++ == *t++) {
      sum++;
    }
  }`

Comment: @user5402 Interesting. Now would you be interested to try the same algorithm using `ByteString`s?

Comment: Using ByteStrings alone doesn't cut it. Your version completed 7/10 test cases. The version here: http://hpaste.org/74202 was able to complete 8/10 test cases, but maybe that was a fluke - I only ran it once.

Comment: Thanks,@user5402. That one's about the same speed as mine for `replicate 50000 'c'`, sometimes a tad slower, sometimes a tad faster, on my box. Haven't tested with more complicated patterns, there might be a difference there, though I don't see a reason why there should be. Anyway, to match the C speed with that algorithm, one would need to go lower level, I think.